# Save app icons as internal assets or provide them from a remote storage?

Tags: angular, performance, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps, angular7

I am developing an Angular 7 shopping list application, PWA with CLI Schematics (@angular/pwa).

The app will provide the shopping icons grouped by item type inside accordions (around 10 to 20 per category, 2KB to 6KB each). The PWA application will be used by mobile phones only (just for context, as this makes no difference).

Since the icons will not change, I am not sure between the following approaches:

1. **Provide all icons as internal assets**
2. **Store the images remotely**

(I am using Firebase as DB, therefore I am thinking to Firebase Storage)

The first approach would have the benefit that all icons are immediately available, but making the overall app size bigger. On the other side, the second would follow more a *lazy loading* approach and only the requested assets will be downloaded and then cached locally. The drawback is an higher loading time to download the icons (at least the first time or when the cache expires).

At the moment I am oriented for the solution no.2, using a PWA lazy load strategy, but I would be curious to know whether there might be better approaches for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third approach, since you only have mobile clients, it means that you almost certainly have service workers. Then you can cache items locally, in the service worker storage. That means, the icons are not loaded the first time the user comes to the site(or you can add a small needed subset of them), but the first time you ask for an icon, it'll get cached, and any other items from the category frmo now on will benefit from it.

If not that, I would better store these as regular assets, rather then firedb items, and then set proper cache controls. In fact, the cache controls should likely be properly set regardless of whether you use service worker or not.

So my TL:DR; answer would be:

- [*] store as static assets on a CDN with proper cache controls
- [ ] use service worker to have them available even faster

(*) => mandatory

This is a solved problem and likely not worth banging your head against the wall about, at least not for long. Use the recommended approach, either service worker or not, don't put static assets in a database.

Also, something to be tested, but you might be able to do these things to:
 - turn them into SVGs (compress much better)
 - send them as sprites

Comment: Zlatko: your suggestion is exactly my solution no.2, thanks for confirming my thoughts. I would store the images on Firebase Cloud Storage (it is an object storage, not a DB). Making my app a PWA, I will use a Service Worker with lazy loading strategy, that is it will not fetch the icons until those are explicitly requested and then it will serve from the cache, if available from there. Good to know that you also would follow such an approach.

Comment: No problem. It's a good, useful question, one has to really put their head into it quite refreshing for a change :)
Sorry for missing the `Firebase Storage` hint - I haven't used firebase for ages, and when I did, it was only to play with it for a while. But yes, if it's possible to address those directly, that's what I would use.